# Dropdown menu show behind div - z-index, overflow, position not working

Tags: css, overflow, dropdown, z-index

I need some help with a dropdown menu that's hiding behind a div. I tried setting the z-index to higher value, set the li to position:relative, checked for overflow in css (none). I see these as common causes for this issue, but nothing works for me.

Please note that z-index, positive and negative, were added whilst trying to find a solution. It makes no difference.

NOTE: dropdown is hiding behind "text-on-banner", yet showing in front of "main-banner".

Thanks for looking at this.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <ul class="PrimaryNav  with-indicator">
                    <li class="Nav-item">
                        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">A</a>
                    <li class="Nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false">B</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="Nav-subitem"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">B.1</a></li>
                                <li class="Nav-subitem"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">B.2</a></li>
                                <li class="Nav-subitem"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">B.3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    <li class="Nav-item">
                        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">C</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-wrapper">
            <div class="main-banner">
                <div class="text-on-banner">
                    <h2><strong>SOME TEXT HERE</strong></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #26282c;
    color:  #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
}

.PrimaryNav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 7px auto;
  max-width: 1220px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.with-indicator {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.Nav-item {
  background: #26282c;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 14.28%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Nav-item a {
  color: #c2c5ca;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Nav-subitem {
  background: #26282c;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.section-wrapper {
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.main-banner {
  text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 2px 1px 2px;
    color: #26282c;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(232, 45, 0, 0.1), 
        inset 0 0 5px rgba(232, 45, 0, 0.2),
        inset -285px 0 35px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff url(banner00.jpg) no-repeat center left;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-on-banner {
    font-weight: 1000;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 95%;
    background-color:white; 
    opacity:0.6;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.text-highlight {
    color: #e82d00;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

Comment: You have some malformed HTML, You have unclosed `li` etc,

Comment: Thanks, Paulie_D. That's actually because I deleted a couple of li, so that it makes the entire thing shorter and easier to read here. Original code has the closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2-3 hours on this, I just realize that it was the .with-indicator ul which had to have z-index > 0. All working as expected now.

Hope this helps somebody else though. Thanks for looking.